# Do quotients by an ideal carry over a ring isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Say we have ring $A$ such that $A \cong B/I$ for some ideal $I$ of $B$, and suppose also that $B \cong C$ for some other ring $C$. Does there exist an ideal $J$ of $C$ such that $A \cong C/J$? Also,  in particular, is $A \cong C/\Phi(I)$, where $\Phi$ is an isomorphism from $B$ to $C$?

This seems intuitively like it should be true, but I'm having a hard time proving it by properties of ideals and isomorphisms alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\rho \colon B \to A$ be a surjective ring homomorphism, and put $I = \ker(\rho)$, so $B/I \cong A$. If $\Phi \colon C \to B$ be an isomorphism, then the composite map $\rho \circ \Phi \colon C \to A$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $\Phi^{-1}(I)$, so $C/\Phi^{-1}(I) \cong A$, as you suspected. In fact, everything above holds if $\Phi$ is only surjective.